# Which sorting has a complexity of $n \log n$ if you compare two elements?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I want to ask just a quick question. If I have an array, which sorting method will have a complexity of $n \log n$ if I compare two objects in that array? I can't decide between `divide-and-conquer`or `insertion-sort`. And how would the iterative solution look like in pseudocode?

Comment: Divide and conquer isn't a sorting method.

Comment: It seems like this question can be answered by reading the Wikipedia article on sorting, so I'm not sure what you expect here.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I compare two objects in that array"?  Obviously you're going to have to compare more than two elements of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion sort has a worst case complexity of $O(n^2)$. "Divide and conquer" is a strategy for designing algorithms, not a sorting method. There are several possible ways to use that for sorting, their complexity isn't always $O(n \log n)$, and the respective pseudocodes are wildly different.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I don't know, in our university, we call it like that. Maybe "merge sort" is more universal. So, you mean, in the comparison the insertion sort is better to prefer, if I want a complexity of `O(n logn)`? The pseudocode should be iteratively, but I can write it myself. I just don't know, which sorting method, I should use.

Comment: Mergesort is a bad match to arrays, you have to copy data around into temporary arrays. Insertion sort is stellar if the input is "almost sorted". Shellsort is simple to code, and reasonably efficient. And so on. See e.g. [Wikipedia's description of sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: Merge sort and quicksort, to mention two, are "divide and conquer" sorting algorithms.

Comment: Obligatory nitpick: you want a $\Theta$ in your first line.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a complete mix-up of terminologies. However, I will try to cover all the possibilities I can.

> Which sorting has a complexity of $n \log n$ if you compare two
>   elements?

Are you asking about worst-case complexity or average-case complexity?
What do you mean by *element*? Do they refer to two sorting algorithms, or two elements of a collection? 
If they are elements of a collection, then you cannot do sorting without comparing two elements.

> If I have an array,

The complexity of an algorithm does not change if you have an array, a set or a list, as long as it is a reasonable data structure.

> I can't decide between `divide-and-conquer` or `insertion-sort`

What decision do you aim to make? What will effect your decision?
The complexity of an algorithm will not change with your decision. Moreover, deciding between divide-and-conquer and insertion sort is like deciding between "buying a sports car" or "going to the cinema by bus". The former is an algorithm type, the latter is a specific algorithm to solve a specific problem.

> And how would the iterative solution look like in pseudocode?

An iterative solution to *what*? Almost all sorting algorithms can be implemented both ways.

Regarding to your question, I think what you ask is

> which sorting algorithms run in $O(n \log n)$ in the worst case?

As can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), there are several sorting algorithms that work in $O(n \log n)$ in the worst case. 
[Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort),
[Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort),
[Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort),
[Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort),
[Cubesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubesort),
[Patience sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_sorting),
[Smoothsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort),
[Tournament sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_sort),
[Block sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort), 
and [Binary tree sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort)

Although, there are more algorithms whose average case are $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: Okay, I really have to apologize here guys. First, my english isn't very well and second I also don't get the task at the first time, because it was a bit longer and complex. The only thing I searched for, was not a sorting method, but a strategy of designing an algorithm (divide-and-conquer I searched for). And I just wanted to know, how a short pseudocode of a divide-and-conquer iterative algorithm would look like, to compare two elements in an array. This algorithm shouldn't change the complexity of my sort-method (n logn). But, okay, next time I ask a question, I will remember this. Thanks